# Reset Skip packages - broke the whole system

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to fix this error "'MSLinqToSQLGenerator' failed". I did the reset skip package steps:
Visual Studio command prompt
navigate to the location of the VS exe 'devenv.exe'

```
devenv /ResetSkipPkgs
```

open LinqToSql files (*.dbml) and save

this broke the whole system. Is there a way to revers or fix this problem quick?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution was to recover an application back up from the previous month and get the server to update.